# Create a div with a triangular pointer on the left

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, html

I need to create a non rectangular div in HTML.

The problem is, both of them are transparent with background. Also, the image inside that div is also a slide show rotating between a set of images.

[image: layout example]

The big image should be rotating. That part is easy enough. The hardest part is that triangle that points to miscellaneous, that is transparent to the rotating picture. And that pointer moves. In this example, this is image set that correspond to miscellaneous. When user click on Food Packing, the pointer must move to point to Food Packing

Any idea how to cut the image to that triangle and keep the color transparent to img, while other parts are transparent to panel background-image?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="rotatorController" id="parent">
    <div id="menu" ng-click="loadList($event)">
        <ul>
            <li>Packaging
                <ul>
                    <li>Food Packing</li>
                    <li>Non Food Packing</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Promotional Item
                <ul>
                    <li>bla bla bla, you got the drift</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch on="pic" ng-animate="'animate'" id="rotator" ng-repeat="image in images">
        <div ng-switch-when="{{$index + 1}}"><img ng-src="{{image}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#parent {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 570px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 40px;
    background: rgb(203, 203, 203);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(203, 203, 203) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgb(203, 203, 203)), color-stop(50%, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(203, 203, 203) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(203, 203, 203) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(203, 203, 203) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(203, 203, 203) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%);
}
div#rotator {
    height: 500px;
    width: 450px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

I need div#rotator to be shaped like that Div B above.. rectangle with a little curve pointing to corresponding menu. Any idea on how to create that?

In short, images are normal rectangular images, but should be cropped like black div with a pointer showing image set's category.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what you're actually trying to do. Seems like an awfully small detail though... you definitely sure you couldn't just cut a few triangle images with hues that roughly match each slide (like a nice middle-ground color), and then swap them out as slides changes? Creating true transparency, without using some sort of "masking" approach sounds like quite the challenge.

Comment: Actually, just to add to my comment above, since you know exactly what vertical position the arrow is going to sit for each slide, you could actually sample that exact shade and cut triangles for each. Then use a little bit of js fading between images and it would be seamless.

Comment: Maybe I should post that as an answer, but I'm only 65% sure I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but the image div has multiple image that keeps rotating from my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540995/self-rotating-image-using-angularjs0) That's complicate the problem.

Comment: The rotating image has variable set of images. I'll attach my php backend and folder hierarchy to understand how it should work in a few hours.. I need to leave now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html5 Canvas can do your indicator using it’s clipping capability**

[image][image]

Here’s the way it works:

- Put the canvas in a div.
- Tell the canvas where to position the indicator (the "Y" coordinate).
- Tell the canvas which image you want to clip inside your irregular canvas div.

This is the function you call to change the canvas image and indicator:

```
        drawCanvasDiv(indicatorYPosition,yourImage);
```

This is the code that draws the irregular box with the image clipped inside:

Once you style your irregular canvas-div exactly as you like it…this code will not change.

```
    function drawCanvasDiv(indicatorY,img){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

        // this call will define the path inside which the image will be clipped
        definePath(indicatorY);

        // clip any image inside the irregularly shaped path
        ctx.clip();

        // draw your desired image
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);

        // finally draw the gray border of the irregular shape
        definePath(indicatorY);
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle="lightgray";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/KYMFn/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    button{ margin:20px; }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var w=canvas.width;
    var h=canvas.height;
    var leftOffset=15;
    var indicatorHeight=20;
    var currentY=125;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        drawCanvasDiv(currentY,img);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/skyGrass.png";


    function drawCanvasDiv(indicatorY,img){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        definePath(indicatorY);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
        definePath(indicatorY);
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle="lightgray";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function definePath(indicatorY){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(leftOffset,0);
        ctx.lineTo(w,0);
        ctx.lineTo(w,h);
        ctx.lineTo(leftOffset,h);
        ctx.lineTo(leftOffset,indicatorY+indicatorHeight/2);
        ctx.lineTo(0,indicatorY);
        ctx.lineTo(leftOffset,indicatorY-indicatorHeight/2);
        ctx.closePath();
    }


    $("#up").click(function(){
        if(currentY-20-indicatorHeight/2>0){ 
            currentY-=20; 
            drawCanvasDiv(currentY,img);
        }
    });

    $("#down").click(function(){
        if(currentY+20+indicatorHeight/2<h){ 
            currentY+=20; 
            drawCanvasDiv(currentY,img);
        }
    });


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=248></canvas><br>
    <button id="up">Indicator Up</button>
    <button id="down">Indicator Down</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow.. you sir, is my savior. I am not using jQuery, but I can work it out from there. No hassle there.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a `background:` or `background-`anything`:` in CSS, in the elements you want your images in, and use a image with transparency, as the `background:url('img.png');`. Remember that you can't add HTML within an `img` tag, so avoid using that as well.

Comment: yes, I know now to set anything on that div, but how can I crop that rectangular picture in a div shaped like that? Images are rectangular

Comment: Use an free image editor like GIMP and create a rectangular transparent background, then add a layer on top of that, creating your shape inside the rectangle. You can use `position:absolute;` to adjust where you want your image with CSS, just make sure your parent element is `position:relative;`.

Comment: I can't crop the images I don't have access. They will upload the image using CMS, and it won't be convenient to told them to crop all images exactly like that. And I can't make sure that the image they upload has the same exact coordinate location as my pointer. The only way is to let browser to shape it. Thanks for the option.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JsFiddle for you.
What i have done is to create a pointer on the side of the Div (purely with CSS - exactly as your black box looks like) and also change where it is pointing with JQuery.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn6Qm/1/)

Tell me if this is what you are looking for.

```
Hope this works for you
```

Cheers

EDIT: I have edited the fiddle for you. [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn6Qm/2/) . I am not able to create exactly what you want so i have done the second best possible solution here. I gave to the triangle a light color with opacity that will give the illusion its transparent.
The problem is that i've created the triangle with the use of borders. You can't set border ...for a border (in order to have the "filling" of the triangle as transparent).

CSS

```
#pointingDiv {
margin:20px;
width: 500px;
height: 350px;
position: relative;
background:url('http://thatgamecompany.com/wp-content/themes/thatgamecompany/_include/img/flower/flower-game-screenshot-2.jpg');
background-size: cover;
}
#pointingDiv:before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
right: 100%;
top: 20px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid rgba(255, 255, 0, .2);
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;  
background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="pointingDiv">   </div>

<p>Click here to change the pointer's location</p>
```

JS (include JQuery)

```
$('p').one('click',function(){
$('head').append('<style>#pointingDiv:before{top: 50px;}</style>');
});
```

I personally don't think there is a way out of this exept if you are willing on cropping the images a bit on the left side and use a bit too much javascript.

Good luck

Comment: It is close, but I need as image shown above, that black div B should be filled the image, and the rest should be transparent to div A background. I put black background, since SO's background is white. I have tried to modify your code a little bit, but it seems I can't achieve what I need.

Comment: Edited/Updated my answer, but that's all i can think of mate. Hope you get what you want and if you find how post it here as well ;-)

Comment: @Thanos Please include the code snippets with your answer so future visitors can benefit even if the jsfiddle goes away.